# Version scheduling for nodes

Tags: nodes

I'm looking for a way (simple) for my editor to save a draft version of an already published node to a later date.

So in other word a way to publish changes on a later date!

Having the possibility to have more than one version on bank would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [Revisioning module](https://drupal.org/project/revisioning)

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your versions of nodes using  [Revisioning module](https://drupal.org/project/revisioning).In addition to it you can use [Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) Moudule to compare between two versions of nodes.

And you can use [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) Module. to schedule the node publish.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) and [Revisioning Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/1103614/git-instructions) modules. You will need to clone the git repo of [Revisioning Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/1103614/git-instructions) since it's in sandbox.

Standard Scheduler module doesn't work well with scheduling of revisions.